How to decide when a variable should be instantiated as a pointer?
Is one pointerism preferred over the other? Whats the difference? The first thing I would think is that at some point, a variable must exist as a non-pointer, for there to ever be a pointer to it, however, we're allowed to instantiate a variable as pointer, so what exactly is preferred, and whats the difference? (other than the obvious).
var pc config                          //  this line
func proxyConf() {
    file, _ := os.ReadFile(proxyConfPath)
    json.Unmarshal(file, &pc)          //  and this line
}

or
var pc *config                         //  this line
func proxyConf() {
    b, _ := os.ReadFile(proxyConfPath)
    json.Unmarshal(file, pc)           //  and this line
}


Does this post answer your question?

@vht981230 informative but I don't think it answers my question.


Your example doesn't work, the second version doesn't populate pc, so it is wrong anyway. 2. This is a question of taste and circumstances (the shown code samples don't help as the second doesn't work).


Generally, when you want a variable to exist, you need to allocates storage for it, either through a declaration or a call of new.
When you do
var pc *config

you are declaring a pointer variable, which is initialized with nil, so no space for a config type has been allocated. you would need pc := new(config) for that.
On the other hand,
var pc config

allocates a storage location for a config type and initialized it with its zero value.
What to use in your program depends on the rest of the code and your coding style. Usually, when you are interested in the value (like you config type), you pass functions that modify the type a pointer, but create the value locally and pass it around by value. If it is a “large” structure, use a pointer.
What you could also use as a rule of thumb, use something that is less tricky and involves less typing. var pc config is clearer than var pc *config; config = new(config) and less error prone, so I would prefer that, when nothing else matters.

A pointer is what it says: a pointer to what is ultimately a physical location in memory. This does not mean the ultimate location must be specified when the pointer is defined, but before it is used in a program to point to something the target location must be defined, possibly through one or more other pointers but ultimately an actual memory location. A pointer may point to a pointer, as many times as you like but ultimately the result must point to a real memory location and data type to be useful.
An example of a pointer being particularly useful is when you have a common routine working on passed parameters. The length of the parameters does not matter, the common routine does not need to allocate memory to work, as the pointer has the ultimate definition of its value, a string, for example, and the routine does not need to allocate space for the maximum length of the parameter value.
In your examples, whether you define pc itself or a pointer to pc depends on the requirements of the program and your preferred programming approach, but before the pointer can be used effectively its ultimate value in memory must be defined. In tricky, but powerful,  situations I sometimes find it is more useful to actually assign memory locations for pointers and variables on a piece of paper and put in actual figures to understand what is going on.

Difference:
Declaring as a pointer gives you flexibility and explicit control over memory but it might generate some complexity (like checking for nil values or dealing with multiple functions/procedures beign able to change this variable).
Declaring as a regular variable and passing its address is simpler and I would use it in case of localized mutability, especially when working with small, scoped variables.
Preference:
I would say that choosing is based on the needs of your code's clarity, performance, and maintainability.
Here below are some of my thoughts about declaring as a pointer VS declaring as regular and passing as a pointer:
In practical scenarios, I believe initialize as pointer are most useful when dynamic memory allocation is required or when you need the ability to reassign the pointer to reference a different variable or memory address. They are also a great choice when working with large data structures, as pointers allow you to avoid the overhead of copying the entire structure by simply passing its memory address.
On the other hand, declaring as regular variables and passing their pointers makes more sense when you want to keep things simple and avoid unnecessary complexity in the variable's declaration. This approach works well when the variable's lifetime and scope are clear and limited, ensuring the data's usage remains straightforward. Additionally, it is particularly effective when the need for mutability is confined to specific function calls, as passing a pointer to a regular variable provides the needed flexibility without introducing the full complexity of pointer-based declarations.
